# Windows scheduled tasks - run task as soon as possible after missed schedule

Tags: scheduled-tasks, command-prompt

Hopefully a nice simple question but I haven't been able to find the solution online. How do I enable the option `Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed` via a command line [`schtasks /create`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772785%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#BKMK_create).

The documentation does not seem to show this option as a command line option and neither does the documentation when using `schtasts /create /?`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Over in the technet forums, [this recommendation was posted](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/1556ded7-257a-43f6-bd14-70b42cbf8415/schtasks-command-line-paramenter-for-run-if-missed?forum=w7itprogeneral):

> As a suggestion, when I've come across missing parameters for this
>   I've made a task manually with the properties I want, exported to XML
>   and then I create the task with something like this: schtasks /create
>   /TN "My New Task Name" /xml "C:\TEMP\My Saved Task.xml" /RU
>   DOMAIN\username /RP password

Comment: see also http://superuser.com/questions/651235/creating-task-with-a-batch-file-run-task-as-soon-as-possible-if-missed